# FilePatterns for Azure Pipelines are not working as expected when using FTP-Upload

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I want to upload my project via FTP to my webserver. Therefore I added a Pipeline in AzureDevOps. I have some folders (which have files and again some folders in it), which should not be uploaded to the webserver. For example the folders .git, .idea, blog and node_modules. My pipeline scripts looks like that:

```
trigger:
- test-stage

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Copy-Item -Path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.htaccess_test -Destination $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.htaccess -force'
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: '$(ftp-url)'
    username: '$(ftp-username)'
    password: '$(ftp-password)'
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    remoteDirectory: '/test'
    trustSSL: true
    enableUtf8: false
    preservePaths: true
    filePatterns: |
      **
      !**/.git/**
      !**/.idea/**
      !**/blog/**
      !**/node_modules/**
```

Even tho the 4 folders are excluded, the content is being loaded on the webserver, for example here:
[image]

So my question is: What is wrong with my pipeline script, especially with the filePatterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with the [FtpUpload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ftp-upload-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task used. But the filePatterns works as expected in [CopyFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task.

So, as a workaround we can copy the project to a temp folder using the [CopyFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) task with the filePatterns set, then upload the files from the temp folder using the [FtpUpload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/ftp-upload-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task.

For example:

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **
      !**/.git/**
      !**/.idea/**
      !**/blog/**
      !**/node_modules/**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\upload'

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: '$(ftp-url)'
    username: '$(ftp-username)'
    password: '$(ftp-password)'
    rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\upload'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/upload/$(Build.BuildId)/'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: false
    preservePaths: true
    trustSSL: false
    enableUtf8: false
```

Comment: @MAESTRO_DE May I know if above solution works for you?

Comment: Wow that works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to the syntax or behavior of the pattern matching in Azure Pipelines.

For testing, try and modify the [file pattern in the FTP upload task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=tfs-2017) to correctly exclude the specified folders *content* (`**/xxx/**/*` instead of `**/xxx/**/`).

```yaml
filePatterns: |
  **/*
  !**/.git/**/*
  !**/.idea/**/*
  !**/blog/**/*
  !**/node_modules/**/*
```

Or:

```yaml
filePatterns: |
  **
  !**/.git/**
  !**/.idea/**
  !**/blog/**
  !**/node_modules/**
```

---

> Both solutions do not work... He uploads the `.git` directory anyway.

Since both file pattern solutions are not working, there might be an underlying issue with how Azure Pipelines interprets the patterns or with the FTP upload task itself.

Make sure the syntax used for the file patterns follows the [Azure Pipelines file matching patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=tfs-2017).

And enable verbose logging for the FTP upload task to get more detailed information on what the task is doing. That might provide insights into why it is uploading the `.git` directory.

As a workaround, consider using multiple FTP upload tasks - one for each directory you want to upload, explicitly specifying the directory in the `rootDirectory` parameter. That would avoid having to use exclusion patterns.

Or: add a pre-processing step in your pipeline to remove or move the directories you do not want to upload. For example, you could move `.git`, `.idea`, `blog`, and `node_modules` to a temporary location before the FTP upload task and then move them back afterward.

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    mv .git ../git_temp
    mv .idea ../idea_temp
    mv blog ../blog_temp
    mv node_modules ../node_modules_temp
  displayName: 'Pre-processing: Move directories out of upload path'

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    # your existing FTP upload configuration 

- script: |
    mv ../git_temp .git
    mv ../idea_temp .idea
    mv ../blog_temp blog
    mv ../node_modules_temp node_modules
  displayName: 'Post-processing: Move directories back'
```

That would temporarily moves the directories you do not want to upload out of the working directory, then moves them back after the upload is complete.

Comment: Both solutions do not work... He uploads the .git directory anyway

Comment: @MAESTRO_DE OK. I have edited the answer with some additional suggestions, for you to test.